# How to copy files of a ZIP file to another folder in Foundry code repository

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I have a ZIP file stored in a foundry data table: `zip_file`

The ZIP file contains files I would like to copy to another folder.

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Output, Input
import zipfile

@transform(
    zip_file = Input('ri.foundry.main.dataset.123')
)
def my_compute_function(ctx, zip_file):

    path_to_store_files_from_zip = 'path/to/store/files/from/zip'

    #what can I do to open zip_file and transfer all files from zip file to 
    #the folder defined in path_to_store_files_from_zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unstructured file access in a code repository.
https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/unstructured-files/

Bear in mind that the output of a transform has to be a dataset or a list of datasets, you won't be able to output files into a Foundry project without putting them into a dataset.